# place tags onto an image that isn't in position absolute

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
                    <img src="test_bg.jpg" class="bg">
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 logo"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2 logo"></div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-center"> Hello </h1>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
$test-color : red;

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.top-header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

.logo{
    background-color: $test-color;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.arrow{
    background-color: $test-color;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I want to have the h1 tag in the middle of the image and the red div in the bottom (.arrow) in the bottom of the image. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it is not normal that you put your background image in your `header` if you want it to cover the page. put it as background for the `body`.

Once it's done, for the red div, you can put the attribute `bottom:0;` so it will stay at the bottom of the page.

For the h1 tag, this could be a solution :

```
position:fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width:30em;
height:18em;
margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
```

Comment: this is not the background image of my webpage it is the background of the first "slide" there will be other under it